# Eclipse autocomplete exits after arbitrary number of keystrokes

Tags: eclipse

I am having an issue with the eclipse autocomplete feature.  Normally autocomplete will give you a list of completions that you can scroll through and choose the correct option with enter.  What started happening to me is that the list will exit after an arbitrary number of keystrokes, as in if I press down three times the third one might arbitrarily just exit the autocomplete box and move my cursor down.  More annoyingly, this often happens when I try to press enter to make a selection.

I have been googling a ton and even tried reinstalling eclipse to no avail.